# Running itch.io game in my android app webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webgl

I have a game made with unity on itch.io I want to open and play this game in my custom android app webview.
For this I'm using.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://teamwood.itch.io/super-auto-pets")
myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Url is being load but on tapping Run Game nothing happen. Can I even perform this in webview

Answer (score 0):

Itch.io supports fullscreen webgl games altough that games can be run in web view if It is not in full screen. For full screen mode you can follow the code like, below is the code of my Game Activity code Which consists simply a web view.

```
package com.example.game

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)
        val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.gameView)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        webView.webViewClient= MyBrowser()
        webView.webChromeClient = MyWebClient(this@GameActivity.applicationContext,this@GameActivity)
        webView.loadUrl("https://teamwood.itch.io/super-auto-pets")
    }

    internal class MyBrowser : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(paramWebView: WebView, paramString: String): Boolean {
            paramWebView.loadUrl(paramString)
            return true
        }
    }



}

open class MyWebClient(private val context: Context,private val activity: GameActivity) : WebChromeClient() {
    private var mCustomView: View? = null
    private var mCustomViewCallback: CustomViewCallback? = null
    protected var mFullscreenContainer: FrameLayout? = null
    private var mOriginalOrientation = 0
    private var mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = 0
    override fun getDefaultVideoPoster(): Bitmap? {
        return if (this == null) {
            null
        } else BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.resources, 2130837573
        )
    }

    override fun onHideCustomView() {
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).removeView(mCustomView)
        mCustomView = null
        activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = mOriginalSystemUiVisibility
        activity.requestedOrientation = mOriginalOrientation
        mCustomViewCallback!!.onCustomViewHidden()
        mCustomViewCallback = null
    }

    override fun onShowCustomView(
        paramView: View?,
        paramCustomViewCallback: CustomViewCallback?
    ) {
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            onHideCustomView()
            return
        }
        mCustomView = paramView
        mOriginalSystemUiVisibility =
            activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility
        mOriginalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback
        (activity.window.decorView as FrameLayout).addView(
            mCustomView,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1)
        )
        activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 3846
    }
}
```